# JMS message from JBoss AS7 to remote JBoss AS4

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I try to send TextMessage via JMS from JBoss 7 client on remote queue which is located on JBoss 4 server.

When server receive the message, exception is thrown:

```
2012-08-24 12:06:26,988 ERROR [ServerThread] Worker thread initialization failure
java.io.IOException: Can not read data for version 0.  Supported versions: 1,2,22
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.versionedRead(ServerThread.java:712)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:572)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:409)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:176)
```

So I added -Djboss.remoting.pre_2_0_compatible=true to jvm arguments but now I got another exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid packet type: 17
    at org.jboss.jms.wireformat.PacketSupport.createPacket(PacketSupport.java:379)
    at org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat.read(JMSWireFormat.java:290)
    at        org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.versionedRead(ServerThread.java:704)
    at   org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:572)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:409)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:176)
```

Could anyone help me how to send message via JMS from JBoss 7 to JBoss 4 server?

Comment: Can you post the client code ?

Comment: Do you have the complete code example?